# Drools Guided Decision table :How to reference fact in action column?

Tags: drools, drools-kie-server

I am trying to use the Guided decision table in Drools Workbench 7.8.0.Final. I am binding a fact pattern for the condition column. Like so:

[image]

I then add a condition for one of the fields.
I now add an action column.

[image]

I bind it to a different fact. I want a field of this fact to be same as person.age.
How can I do this in the decision table?
It seems to allow only constants

[image]

p.age is taken to be a string constant. Not what I want.